# Jest coverage missing branches on import statement inside lcov report

Tags: testing, jestjs, code-coverage, lcov, coveralls

I am trying to figure out why I am having missing branches on import files when checking the Jest Coverage **lcov** report.

I have 100% line coverage, but other types of coverage (statement, branch, and functions) are pretty low. I wasn't sure about the reason so I checked the HTML report that jest creates with **lcov**, and when I checked, I saw that there are a lot of import statements that are marked with many missing branches warnings.

E.g (report on coveralls):
[image]

Not sure what a missing branch warning over an import means, maybe they are not for the import line but for the file in general. So my concern is, why do I have a warning on an import statement? how do I cover an import statement? am I missing additional configuration?